# Finding Occurrence of numbers in a String

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Goal is to fetch numbers which are followed by RatesLowerBound as variable rates and numbers which are alone fetch them as fixed rates.

```
Input String :- 'Basis(DataKeyBasisAmount(basisProperty=INPUT_EPSO_PAYMENT_AMOUNT)) [+0.05] RateLowerBound(value=2, inclusive=false) | [+0.07] RateLowerBound(value=5, inclusive=false) | [+0.10] RateLowerBound(value=20, inclusive=false) | [+0.35]'
Expected Output :- Var_Rate_1, Var_Rate_2, Var_Rate_3 , Fixed Rate
                     +0,05       +0.07       +0.10        +0.35
```

Tried the below sql code to fetch the results. It's giving expected output

```
SELECT Col1,
        REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1,'\\[[^]]*',1,1),'[','') AS Var_Rate_1
        ,REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1,'\\[[^]]*',1,2),'[','') AS Var_Rate_1
        ,REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1,'\\[[^]]*',1,3),'[','') AS Var_Rate_1
        ,REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1,'\\[[^]]*',1,4),'[','') AS Fixed_Rate_1
FROM (SELECT 'Basis(DataKeyBasisAmount(basisProperty=INPUT_EPSO_PAYMENT_AMOUNT)) [+0.05] RateLowerBound(value=2, inclusive=false) | [+0.07] RateLowerBound(value=5, inclusive=false) | [+0.10] RateLowerBound(value=20, inclusive=false) | [+0.35]' AS Col1);
```

But the problem is that order of fixed rates and variable rates can change in input string. For Example :- In the example string Fixed Rate is appearing in last but in other string it can appear as first element. So it's making difficult to tag to based on position.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
SELECT LEFT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, '.{6} RateLowerBound', 1, 1), 5) AS Var_Rate_1,
       LEFT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, '.{6} RateLowerBound', 1, 2), 5) AS Var_Rate_2,
       LEFT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, '.{6} RateLowerBound', 1, 3), 5) AS Var_Rate_3,
       LEFT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, '.{6} RateLowerBound', 1, 4), 5) AS Var_Rate_4
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. It's working for Rate Lower Band but not returning Fixed band.

Comment: @GauravS . . . "Goal is to fetch numbers which are followed by RatesLowerBound".  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: I have mentioned that in question. Please refer to "numbers which are alone fetch them as fixed rates." . Also i have a column for that in expected output. Hope it clarifies.